# Vim settings within ncftp edit

Tags: vim, configuration, ncftp

I'm using the `ncftp` utility.  It has an `edit` command which handles the get, edit, put sequence for me as in GUI ftp clients.

It's great except for one thing, I get vanilla `vim`, with none of my settings.  Ideally, I'd like to have it configured exactly the same as outside of `ncftp` (colors, key mappings, pathogen bundles, etc).

How can I force vim to load my settings when invoked from within `ncftp`?

NCFTP relies on the following environment variable to find the editor:

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vi" ; export EDITOR
```

Can that somehow be tweaked to force load my settings?

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/vi` a correct link to `/usr/bin/vim`? Otherwise, you could try to set your EDITOR to `/usr/bin/vim`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the EDITOR environment variable like so:

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"; export EDITOR
```

Also if you have an alternative to $HOME/.vimrc that you want to use instead you could do the following:

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim -u $HOME/.othervimrc"; export EDITOR
```

Answer (score 0):

vim isn't loading vanilla. What's happening is the file you're editing isn't recognized because it is a temporary file.

```
ncftp / > edit appiniconfig.sh

Please wait while appiniconfig.sh is downloaded for editing.
/tmp/ncftp_editcmd.L1XVxZ:                             130.00 B    2.87 kB/s
```

Notice how you're actually editing ncftp_editcms.L1XVxZ. It is unfortunate that if you do care about syntax highlighting, you'll have to `:set ft=javascript` (or whatever) and I also want a nicer solution.

Sorry for this being a non-answer.